Springboot + JPA + Snowflake COPY INTO issue
I try to execute INSERT / COPY INTO from java to snowflake via S3 stage.
File in S3 exists / file is not empty / table exists / I have all permissions to that table.
I use Java 21, Springboot 3.3.2 and snowflake-jdbc 3.18.0
Process always complete with success but with "number of rows inserted=0" response.
My repository class looks like that:
@Repository
public interface BlahBlahRepository extends JpaRepository<BlahBlah, String> {

    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO BLABLA (A, B, C) SELECT s.$1 AS A, s.$2 AS B, s.$3 AS C FROM @SOME_STAGE/some-folder/:filename s;", nativeQuery = true)
    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true, flushAutomatically = true)
    List<Map<String, String>> copyFromStage(@Param("filename") String filename);
}

I've tried to experiment with transactions/isolations/etc. Nothing helped.
When checked in ACCOUNT_USAGE.COPY_HISTORY (for COPY INTO) there were no entries (btw. I know about propagation lag ~45min). Additionally for COPY INTO I used FORCE=TRUE - didn't help.
Any ideas why that particular command does not work? All other "normal" sql commands work well.

I guess currently (Oct, 2024) this is not supported. I've bypassed that by defining function in Snowflake which do the COPY INTO maneuver and then calling it from native query in java.
